# Printing multi-page files from shell script in a printer with cutter

Tags: bash, macos, unix, printing

Im writing a shell script to automate the process of printing a significant pool of images. The script consists in two parts:

1) It converts all the images in a directory into a unique pdf file (where each image becomes a page).
2) The pdf file is sent to the printer queue.

The problem comes when I send to print the pdf from lp command, it stops the job after the first page is printed. I tried to "force" printing all pages adding the option -page-ranges=1-9999 with no results, but Im able to print any page in the file adding the page number in the -page-ranges option.  However when I send the pdf file from the system printing dialog I get all pages printed.

The printer uses a roll of continuous paper (a photographic printer) and it's in a macos environment.

I also tried to send all images directly without adding them to a pdf file, but even they are in the printing queue as a single job the printer treats them as individual jobs (which means a lot of wasted paper as the printer makes 4 5mm cuts before printing the first image in a job).

So at this point, Im looking for a solution with the printing proccess. Whatever clean or not and both in any other language or system environment whereas it does not implies someone clicking 'OK' in a dialog interface to send the files to the printer.

Comment: So, please to have a chance to be helped, share what you already did.

Comment: Hi @Meloman, Im not having problems with the code itself as it does the job when sended to a regular printer. The problem comes in how to properly communicate with a printer that uses a continuous roll of paper instead of paper sheets. But anyways, this is the lp commands I use in the script:
lp -d $printer -o media=Custom=102x146mm file.pdf

lp -d $printer -o media=Custom.102x146mm $(find "$path_to_dir" -type f -iname "*.jpg")